# Kendo UI Window.refresh({ data }) not being passed to ASP.Net MVC action properly

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-window

I have a window:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Window()
   .Name("wndInvoiceLineEditor")
   .Title("Invoice Line Item Editor")
   .Content("loading dialog...")
   .Height(350)
   .Width(785)
   .LoadContentFrom("InvoiceLineItemEditor", "Invoice", new { LineItemId = "Initial" })
   .Draggable()
   .Resizable()
   .Visible(false)
)
```

I need to be able to re-load that partial view, with different data passed along at runtime. As far as I read in the documentation, I should be able to do this:

```
$("#wndInvoiceLineEditor").data("kendoWindow").refresh({
   data: {
      LineItemId: $($(".k-state-selected td")[0]).text()
   }
});
```

However the action server-side:

```
public ActionResult InvoiceLineItemEditor(string LineItemId)
{
   int id = 0;
   if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(LineItemId) || !int.TryParse(LineItemId, out id))
   { 
      return PartialView("InvoiceLineItemEditorPartial", new InvoiceLineItem());
   }

   ...blah blah blah
```

...doesn't receive the proper ID (the jquery to grab it from the table DOES work, has been tested via Chrome console)

Instead, it receives the data as configured in the view: "Initial".

Am I missing something? How do I get the data sent back to the action so I can load that partial with the right information?

ANSWERED:

The problem was the default data being set up in the LoadContentFrom part of the window initialization in the view. Changing it to:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Window()
   .Name("wndInvoiceLineEditor")
   .Title("Invoice Line Item Editor")
   .Content("loading dialog...")
   .Height(350)
   .Width(785)
   .LoadContentFrom("InvoiceLineItemEditor", "Invoice")
   .Draggable()
   .Resizable()
   .Visible(false)
)
```

...fixes the problem. The window was set, seemingly immovably, to that default value.

Comment: Please write your solution as an accepted answer to your question, else it is not immediately obvious that this problem has a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the default data being set up in the LoadContentFrom part of the window initialization in the view. Changing it to:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Window()
   .Name("wndInvoiceLineEditor")
   .Title("Invoice Line Item Editor")
   .Content("loading dialog...")
   .Height(350)
   .Width(785)
   .LoadContentFrom("InvoiceLineItemEditor", "Invoice")
   .Draggable()
   .Resizable()
   .Visible(false)
)
```

...fixes the problem. The window was set, seemingly immovably, to that default value.